# reasons not to use dataset binding in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, dataset

I have this question. everyone seems to like to use the feature dataset binding in vb.net. I was wondering is there any reason that this approach is better than the time I handle the binding myself in code? I mean creating the sqlConnection open it and... so on.

thanks a lot.

Comment: "creating the sql connection open it and so on" is not binding. How you manage the connection is a separate issue from binding, which is how you get data to/from the UI.

Comment: by binding i mean bind the datasource visually in visual studio in Server explorer part > Connect to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment *that's not binding*. 
I think this is one of the many situations where a feature that helps you get started with something small can start to get in the way when you are tackling a bigger and more complex project. Particularly if you are building a system to distribute to multiple clients, who will then have to install and configure the system for themselves, I'd recommend you manage the connections in code; you need that degree of control over what's going on.
Conversely if you're writing a little utility to be used in-house you can rely on the connection management provided by VS. Personally anything but the simplest application I manage the connections in code.